# Truffle config solc version pragma not found

Tags: blockchain, truffle

I'm trying to compile a smart contract, truffle cannot find the solc when using this compiler configuration. It cannot autodetect the solc version from the source files.

```js
module.exports = {
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: 'pragma',
            optimizer: {
                enabled: true,
                runs: 200,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Result of `truffle compile` execution

```
Error: Could not find a compiler version matching pragma. compilers.solc.version option must be a string specifying:
   - a path to a locally installed solcjs
   - a solc version or range (ex: '0.4.22' or '^0.5.0')
   - a docker image name (ex: 'stable')
   - 'native' to use natively installed solc
```

truffle solc documentation

```
solc¶
Solidity compiler settings. Supports optimizer settings for solc, as well as other settings such as debug and metadata settings.

You may specify... 
+ any solc-js version (using semver) listed at solc-bin. Specify the one you want and Truffle will get it for you. 
+ "native" to use a natively compiled solc binary (you'll need to install this yourself, links to help below). 
+ a dockerized solc tag from one of images published here. 
+ a path to a locally available solc 
+ "pragma" to have Truffle autodetect solc versions from your source files. This can be used to compile using multiple versions of solc. 
+ a solc-js parser for faster docker and native compilations
```

Comment: Can you run `truffle compile --list` to check which versions of solc you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I decided to investigate what the problem might be and found out that if you have different versions of files in your project, you can specify `pragma` and compile files with different versions. I found out about it from [here](https://trufflesuite.com/blog/take-a-dive-into-truffle-5/index.html#pragma-compilation)

As I understand it, this functionality is available from truffle version 5.2.0 and higher. I also found a great repository with an example that will most likely be able to help - [v5.2-example-box](https://github.com/truffle-box/v5.2-example-box). Most likely if you compare your project with this one you will surely be able to find the error.

---

#### Initial answer

I would suggest installing a specific version of `solc` as suggested in the [documentation](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration.html#solc) to check if there are any other issues.

For my work I use the following settings in `truffle-config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '0.8.3',
      parser: 'solcjs'
    }
  }
}
```

You also need to install a specific version of the package. Which will match the version from `truffle-config.js`, in this case, this version is `0.8.3`.

To install the package, you need to call one of these commands for **npm** or **yarn**, depending on what you are using.

```
npm i solc@0.8.3

yarn add solc@0.8.3
```

Also in my case, there is such a version in the contract:

```js
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;
```

Comment: It did work using `'pragma'` as the `solc` version, I don't need a specific version for now. In the documentation, it says that it should auto-detect the version from the source files but fails to do so.

Comment: Can you try to run - `truffle compile` ?

Comment: check the update above